# Problems in deleting a dll at uninstall using INNO setup

Tags: dll, inno-setup, uninstallation

I am using the GameuxInstallHelper.dll to register my game at installation with Games Explorer.

But for some the reason the dll remains in my application folder after uninstall, but only on Win XP. On Win 7 and Vista all files are deleted.

The code used:

```
function CheckXPOs(): Boolean;
begin
  if GetWindowsVersion shr 24 < 6 then Result:=TRUE
end;

procedure CurUninstallStepChanged(CurUninstallStep: TUninstallStep);
var
  mres : integer;
begin
  if CurUninstallStep = usUninstall then
    begin
      #ifdef AddToGameExplorer
      if not CheckXPOs then
        begin
          RetrieveGUIDForApplication(ExpandConstant('{app}'+GE_resource), GUID);
          RemoveFromGameExplorer(GUID);
          RemoveTasks(GUID);
          UnloadDll(ExpandConstant('{app}\GameuxInstallHelper.dll'));
        end;
      #endif
    end;
    case CurUninstallStep of
    usPostUninstall:
      begin
        mres := MsgBox(ExpandConstant('{cm:removemsg}'), mbConfirmation, MB_YESNO)
          if mres = IDYES then
            DelTree(ExpandConstant('{app}'), True, True, True);
      end;
     end;
end;
```

Any idea why the dll is not deleted on XP OS's and how can i delete it?
I've tried the DeleteFile function after unloading the dll, i've also tried to make another function to search for that specific dll, but nothing helped me solve the problem.
And the dll is not in use, because manually the OS is letting me delete it.

Comment: @stukelly did change something in the code? 'cause i can't see any visible difference.

Comment: no I just added the inno-setup tag.

Comment: You mention you tried with DeleteFile, but yo do not explain if you get a error message when doing that.  It is possible the file is in use during uninstallation, but you'll know it by inspecting the last OS Error if the DeleteFunction fails.

Comment: OK, instead of copying the dll to my application folder i decided to send it to {sys}. But when i uninstall my program i'm still receiving that message box saying "My Program uninstall complete.
Some elements could not be removed. These can be removed manually.". The interesting part is that my application folder no longer exist, it's being deleted. So now i only need to get rid of that message box. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should unload dll after the "not CheckXPOs" block.

```pascal
if not CheckXPOs then
begin
  RetrieveGUIDForApplication(ExpandConstant('{app}'+GE_resource), GUID);
  RemoveFromGameExplorer(GUID);
  RemoveTasks(GUID);
end;
UnloadDll(ExpandConstant('{app}\GameuxInstallHelper.dll'));
```

Another way is adding `"delayload"` option in declaration of all functions loaded from GameuxInstallHelper.dll